# Get discussion forum post body using id or url in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have a discussion forum post url like `http://example.com/ALIF/Lists/Discussion Forum 2/DispForm.aspx?ID=879` or id `879'.

How to retrieve discussion body from the list using url or id?

Comment: Through the web services or via the object model?